# Cannot resolve symbol FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

How do I insert the FirebaseListAdapter correctly? I always get the error "Can not resolve FirebaseListAdapter". If you need something, I'll post it. The whole is supposed to spend chat messages. The error is output in line 26.

My code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class Chat extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter; //here is the problem

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            // Start sign in/sign up activity
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .build(),
                    SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
            );
        } else {
            // User is already signed in. Therefore, display
            // a welcome Toast
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Willkommen " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                            .getCurrentUser()
                            .getDisplayName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            // Load chat room contents
            displayChatMessages();
        }

        FloatingActionButton fab =
                (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

                // Read the input field and push a new instance
                // of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference()
                        .push()
                        .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                                        .getCurrentUser()
                                        .getDisplayName())
                        );

                // Clear the input
                input.setText("");
            }
        });




    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_sign_out) {
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(Chat.this,
                                    "You have been signed out.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();

                            // Close activity
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Erfolgreich eingeloggt. Willkommen!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                displayChatMessages();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again later.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                // Close the app
                finish();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    private void displayChatMessages() {
        ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
                R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
                // Get references to the views of message.xml
                TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

                // Set their text
                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

                // Format the date before showing it
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                        model.getMessageTime()));
            }
        };

        listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Build Gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.bluestarfish.bluestarfish"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "0.3.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'

}

// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: The constructors of the adapters have changed in version 3.x. Please follow the instructions from the FirebaseUI documentation here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructors of the adapters have changed in version 3.x. Please follow the [instructions from the FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview):

> ```
> FirebaseListOptions<Chat> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Chat>()
>         .setQuery(query, Chat.class)
>         .build();
>
> FirebaseListAdapter<Chat> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Chat>(options) {
>     @Override
>     protected void populateView(View v, Chat model, int position) {
>         // Bind the Chat to the view
>         // ...
>     }
> };
> ```

Comment: Too bad, my experience is not enough. Thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do it with the documentation. Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not have enough reputation to vote