# Firebase list adapter in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have some problem in the android studio , i want to create the list view conect with the Firebase .

But i get this error :

> cannot resolve symbol firebaselistadapter

**this is my dependence:**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
```

I try a lot and i Chang the dependence but i cant solve it , can any one help me ples i am new in the android studio .

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849553/cannot-resolve-symbol-firebaselistadapter]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
```

You are already using `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0` so you don't need to add `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3` that will give you a very old version of `firebaseui`

Comment: Thank you but when i delete the firebase-client i get this error: package com.firebase.client does not exist

Comment: @programmer you are probably reading an old tutorial because the com.firebase.client is a very old dependency that you shouldn't use.. The dependency was before Google acquired Firebase. Check here on how to configure https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup